# Use of check_admin_referer with theme options and options.php

Tags: theme-options, nonce

If I set up a theme options page in the way suggested by the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)
then my form submits to 'option.php'.

`settings_fields` creates a nonce, which if I was creating my own submission page would be checked with `check_admin_referer`.

My question then.... if I use options.php as my 'form processor' does this mean I cannot use `check_admin_referer`?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `check_admin_referer`. If you are using the Settings API then WordPress handles nonce checking and saving data to the database.

In terms of data validation, the only thing you need to provide is a validation callback. This callback receives all inputs with name specified in the second argument of [`register_setting`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) (I often use this name to store an array of all my plugin option - so I only register one setting). The callback is specified in the third argument of `register_setting` and is responsible for returning the validated setting(s).